# ¿Por qué no se añaden los nuevos datos al arhivo XML?

Tags: php, html, xml

Estoy empezando con XML y quiero meter con PHP elementos nuevos en el archivo con la extensión XML.

El código PHP coge la información de un formulario HTML y lo inserta en una base de datos y un arhivo XML. Al hacer el addchild los valores que paso ('Hau galdera izango zen','Hemen erantzun zuzena' y 'Hemen erantzun okerra')
 son simplemente para hacer la prueba. Cuando se inserten estos los cambiaré por los valores del formulario de HTML.
El código del archivo PHP sería el siguiente:

```
$xmlstr="../XML/questions.xml";

$local = 0;
if($local == 0){
    $server ="localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "";
    $db = "quiz";
}else{
    $server ="localhost";
    $user = "id3001514_t17";
    $pass = "12345";
    $db = "id3001514_quiz";
}
$konektatu = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $db);

$sql = "INSERT INTO questions VALUES('','$_POST[posta]', '$_POST[galdera]', '$_POST[zuzena]', '$_POST[okerra1]','$_POST[okerra2]','$_POST[okerra3]', '$_POST[zailtasuna]', '$_POST[arloa]')";
if (file_exists($xmlstr)) {
    $questions =  simplexml_load_file($xmlstr);
    $simpleXML = new SimpleXMLElement($questions->asXML());
    $question = $simpleXML->addChild('assessmentItem');
    $question->addChild('itemBody','Hau galdera izango zen');
    $correct=$question->addChild('correctResponse');
    $correct->addChild('value','Hemen erantzun zuzena');
    $incorrect=$question->addChild('incorrectResponse');
    $incorrect->addChild('value','Hemen erantzun okerra');
    $incorrect->addChild('value','Hemen Bigarrena');
    $simpleXML->asXML($xmlstr); 

} else {
    echo "Error, no se pudo abrir el archivo XML, revise la ruta y si existe";
}
$execute=mysqli_query($konektatu,$sql);
if(!$execute){
    echo"Ezin izan dira datuak txertatu. ".mysqli_error($konektatu);
}else{
    echo"Datuak txertatu egin dira";
    echo"<a href=../HTML5/showQuestions.php> Ikusi Datuak </a><br>";
    echo'<a href=../PHP/showXMLQuestions.php>Ikusi Datuak (XML) </a>';
}
mysqli_close($konektatu);
```

El archivo XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"   encoding="UTF-8"  ?>
<assessmentItems>

    <assessmentItem complexity="3" subject="mikologia">

        <itemBody> 

            <p>Zein Amanita da jangarria?</p>

        </itemBody>

        <correctResponse>

            <value>Caesarea</value>

        </correctResponse>

        <incorrectResponses>

            <value>Phalloides</value>

            <value>Muscaria</value>

            <value>Virosa</value>

        </incorrectResponses>

    </assessmentItem>

    <assessmentItem complexity="3" subject="mikologia">

        <itemBody> 

            <p>Tripakiek zer dute kapela azpian?</p>

        </itemBody>

        <correctResponse>

            <value>Eztenak</value>

        </correctResponse>

        <incorrectResponses>

            <value>Filamenduak</value>

            <value>Himenioa</value>

            <value>Hodiak</value>

        </incorrectResponses>

    </assessmentItem>

    <assessmentItem complexity="5" subject="mikologia">

        <itemBody>

            <p>Eranztuna du</p>

        </itemBody>

        <correctResponse>

            <value>Galanpernak</value>

        </correctResponse>

        <incorrectResponses>

            <value>Gibel urdinak</value>

            <value>Esnegorriak</value>

            <value>Errotariak</value>

        </incorrectResponses>

    </assessmentItem>

</assessmentItems>
```

El error que da es esta línea:
`$simpleXML = new SimpleXMLElement($questions->asXML());`y el error es el siguiente:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function asXML() on boolean in C:\xaaamp\htdocs\lab4\PHP\addQuestion.php:21 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xaaamp\htdocs\lab4\PHP\addQuestion.php on line 21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que veo tú quieres agregar algo así:

```
<assessmentItems>
...
    <assessmentItem>

        <itemBody> 
            <p>Hau galdera izango zen</p>
        </itemBody>

        <correctResponse>
            <value>Hemen erantzun zuzena</value>
        </correctResponse>

        <incorrectResponses>
            <value>Hemen erantzun okerra</value>
            <value>Hemen Bigarrena</value>
        </incorrectResponses>

    </assessmentItem>
...
</assessmentItems>
```

Primeramente, verifica que el archivo se está cargando correctamente.

Luego, tienes que valerte de `SimpleXMLElement` para obtener el archivo y guardar los cambios.

También, siendo `assessmentItems` el root del XML, tendrías que proceder como se muestra en el código para empezar a añadir nuevos `assessmentIntem`.

En cuanto a los `value` de las respuestas correctas e incorrectas también hay que varia el código.

Veamos:

```
$xmlstr='../XML/questions.xml';

if (file_exists($xmlstr)) {

$questions =  simplexml_load_file($xmlstr);
$simpleXML = new SimpleXMLElement($questions->asXML());
$question = $simpleXML->addChild('assessmentItem');
$question->addChild('itemBody','Hau galdera izango zen');
$correct=$question->addChild('correctResponse');
    $correct->addChild('value','Hemen erantzun zuzena');
$incorrect=$question->addChild('incorrectResponse');
    $incorrect->addChild('value','Hemen erantzun okerra');
    $incorrect->addChild('value','Hemen Bigarrena');

$simpleXML->asXML($xmlstr); 

} else {

echo "Error, no se pudo abrir el archivo XML, revise la ruta y si existe";

}
```

---

**Nota:** En algunos casos, por motivos que no conozco, el código anterior podría dar el error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function asXML() on
>   boolean...

En ese caso, funcionará el código de la siguiente forma:

```
    $xmlstr='myxml.xml';

    if (file_exists($xmlstr)) {

    $questions =  simplexml_load_file($xmlstr);
    $question = $questions->addChild('assessmentItem');
    $question->addChild('itemBody','Hau galdera izango zen');
    $correct=$question->addChild('correctResponse');
        $correct->addChild('value','Hemen erantzun zuzena');
    $incorrect=$question->addChild('incorrectResponse');
        $incorrect->addChild('value','Hemen erantzun okerra');
        $incorrect->addChild('value','Hemen Bigarrena');
    $questions->asXML($xmlstr); 

} else {

    echo "Error, no se pudo abrir el archivo XML, revise la ruta y si existe";

}
```

---

El código escribirá esto en el archivo:

```
<assessmentItem>

    <itemBody>Hau galdera izango zen</itemBody>

    <correctResponse>
        <value>Hemen erantzun zuzena</value>
    </correctResponse>

    <incorrectResponse>
        <value>Hemen erantzun okerra</value>
        <value>Hemen Bigarrena</value>
    </incorrectResponse>

</assessmentItem>
```

Comment: He pegado tu código y me da un error, editaré el hilo poniendo el nuevo error.

Comment: @MikelMolinuevo yo lo he probado y funciona a la perfección... Espero ver cuál es el error. Indica también tu versión de PHP si es posible.

Comment: Ya lo tienes editado. La versión del PHP es  la 7.1.8

Comment: Yo lo probé en PHP 7 y me funciona bien. En tu caso hay algo mal aquí: `$questions =  simplexml_load_file($xmlstr);`, está devolviendo `false` en vez del objeto XML. ¿La ruta del archivo está bien? ¿Tiene permisos de escritura?

Comment: Está bien la ruta y tengo todos los permisos. No sé que puede ser...

Comment: @MikelMolinuevo edita tu pregunta poniendo el código como lo tienes actualmente.

Comment: Ya está editado

Comment: Es extraño, cambia todo el bloque así: `$questions =  simplexml_load_file($xmlstr);
 $question = $questions->addChild('assessmentItem');
    $question->addChild('itemBody','Hau galdera izango zen*****');
    $correct=$question->addChild('correctResponse');
  $correct->addChild('value','Hemen erantzun zuzena');
    $incorrect=$question->addChild('incorrectResponse');
     $incorrect->addChild('value','Hemen erantzun okerra');
  $incorrect->addChild('value','Hemen Bigarrena');
 $questions->asXML($xmlstr);`

Comment: Vale ya funciona. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Me alegro @MikelMolinuevo he editado la respuesta poniendo las dos posibilidades de código. Saludos.